# How to check version of IE on Windows 7 with PowerShell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, internet-explorer, powershell

I want to check which version of IE I have on my Windows 7 machine. I would like to do this with the command line, either through Command Prompt or PowerShell. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I check the version of IE on Windows 7 from a command line?

From a command line:

```
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v version ^| find "version"`)  do echo IE version: %a
```

---

#### What if I want to use a batch file?

From a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%a in (`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v version ^| find "version"`)  do echo IE version: %%a
```

In a batch file you need to replace each `%` with `%%`.

---

#### What is the output from the above commands?

On my PC I get the following output:

```
IE version: 9.11.9600.17691
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.

Answer (score 4):

And, for Powershell....

```
$IEVersionString = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe").Fileversion
write-host $IEVersionString
```

Mine yields...

> 11.00.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)